# An algorithm to calculate probability of a sum of the results happening

Tags: c, algorithm, probability

The algorithm I'm talking about using would allow you to present it with x number of items with each having a range of a to b with the result being y. I would like to have an algorithm which would, when presented with the values as described would output the possibility of it happening.

For example, for two die. Since I already know them(due to the possible results being so low). It'd be able to tell you each of the possibilities.

The setup would be something like. x=2 a=1 b=6. If you wanted to know the chance of having it result in a 2. Then it'd simply spit out 1/36(or it's float value). If you put in 7 as the total sum, it'd tell you 6.

So my question is, is there a simple way to implement such a thing via an algorithm that is already written. Or does one have to go through every single iteration of each and every item to get the total number of combinations for each value.

The exact formula would also, give you the combinations to make each of the values from 1-12.

So it'd give you a distribution array with each one's combinations at each of the indexes. If it does 0-12. Then 0 would have 0, 1 would have 0, and 2 would have 1.

I feel like this is the type of problem that someone else has had and wanted to work with and has the algorithm already done. If anyone has an easy way to do this beyond simply just looping through every possible value would be awesome.

I have no idea why I want to have this problem solved, but for some reason today I just had this feeling of wanting to solve it. And since I've been googling, and using wolfram alpha, along with trying it myself. I think it's time to concede defeat and ask the community.

I'd like the algorithm to be in c, or maybe PHP(even though I'd rather it not be since it's a lot slower). The reason for c is simply because I want raw speed, and I don't want to have to deal with classes or objects.

Pseudo code, or C is the best ways show your algorithm.

Edit:

Also, if I offended the person with a 'b' in his name due to the thing about mathematics I'm sorry. Since I didn't mean to offend, but I wanted to just state that **I** didn't understand it. But the answer could've stayed on there since I'm sure there are people who might come to this question and understand the mathematics behind it.

Also I cannot decide which way that I want to code this up. I think I'll try using both and then decide which one I like more to see/use inside of my little library.

The final thing that I forgot to say is that, calculus is about four going on five years ago. My understanding of probability, statistics, and randomness come from my own learning via looking at code/reading wikipedia/reading books.

If anyone is curious what sparked this question. I had a book that I was putting off reading called *The Drunkards Walk* and then once I say XKCD 904, I decided it was time to finally get around to reading it. Then two nights ago, whilst I was going to sleep... I had pondered how to solve this question via a simple algorithm and was able to think of one.

My coding understanding of code comes from tinkering with other programs, seeing what happened when I broke something, and then trying my own things whilst looking over the documentation for the build in functions. I do understand big O notation from reading over wikipedia(as much as one can from that), and pseudo code was because it's so similar to python. I myself, cannot write pseudo code(or says the teachers in college). I kept getting notes like "make it less like real code make it more like pseudo code." That thing hasn't changed.

Edit 2: Incase anyone searching for this question just quickly wanted the code. I've included it below. It is licensed under the LGPLv3 since I'm sure that there exists closed-source equivalents of this code.

It should be fairly portable since it is written entirely in c. If one was wanting to make it into an extension in any of the various languages that are written in c, it should take very little effort to do so. I chose to 'mark' the first one that linked to "Ask Dr. Math" as the answer since it was the implementation that I have used for this question.

The first file's name is "sum_probability.c"

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/*!
*    file_name: sum_probability.c
*    
*    Set of functions to calculate the probabilty of n number of items adding up to s
*    with sides x. The question that this program relates to can be found at the url of
*    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394120/
*    
*     Copyright 2011-2019, Macarthur Inbody
*    
*   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
*   it under the terms of the Lesser GNU General Public License as published by
*   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
*   (at your option) any later version.
*
*   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
*   GNU General Public License for more details.
*
*   You should have received a copy of the Lesser GNU General Public License
*   along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.html>.
*     
*   2011-06-20 06:03:57 PM -0400
*    
*   These functions work by any input that is provided. For a function demonstrating it.
*   Please look at the second source file at the post of the question on stack overflow.
*   It also includes an answer for implenting it using recursion if that is your favored
*   way of doing it. I personally do not feel comfortable working with recursion so that is
*   why I went with the implementation that I have included.
*
*/

/*
* The following functions implement falling factorials so that we can
* do binomial coefficients more quickly.
* Via the following formula.
*
*   K
*  PROD    (n-(k-i))/i
*   i=1;
*
*/

//unsigned int return
unsigned int m_product_c( int k,  int n){
    int i=1;
    float result=1;
    for(i=1;i<=k;++i){
        result=((n-(k-i))/i)*result;
    }
    return result;
}

//float return
float m_product_cf(float n, float k){
    int i=1;
    float result=1;
    for(i=1;i<=k;++i){
        result=((n-(k-i))/i)*result;
    }
    return result;
}


/*
* The following functions calculates the probability of n items with x sides
* that add up to a value of s. The formula for this is included below.
*
* The formula comes from. http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52207.html
*
*s=sum
*n=number of items
*x=sides
*(s-n)/x
* SUM  (-1)^k * C(n,k) * C(s-x*k-1,n-1)
* k=0
*
*/

float chance_calc_single(float min, float max, float amount, float desired_result){
    float range=(max-min)+1;
    float series=ceil((desired_result-amount)/range);
    float i;
    --amount;
    float chances=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<=series;++i){
        chances=pow((-1),i)*m_product_cf(amount,i)*m_product_cf(desired_result-(range*i)-1,amount)+chances;
    }
    return chances;
}
```

And here is the file that shows the implementation as I said in the previous file.

```
#include "sum_probability.c"

/*
* 
* file_name:test.c
*
* Function showing off the algorithms working. User provides input via a cli
* And it will give you the final result.
*
*/
int main(void){
        int amount,min,max,desired_results;
        printf("%s","Please enter the amount of items.\n");
        scanf("%i",&amount);
        printf("%s","Please enter the minimum value allowed.\n");
        scanf("%i",&min);
        printf("%s","Please enter the maximum value allowed.\n");
        scanf("%i",&max);
        printf("%s","Please enter the value you wish to have them add up to. \n");
        scanf("%i",&desired_results);
        printf("The total chances for %i is %f.\n", desired_results, chance_calc_single(min, max, amount, desired_results));
}
```

Comment: absolutely not. I woke up today and had this question in my head. But I wanted to make it efficient. It was like the other day, when I completely rewrote the prng inside of PHP so that it had used better sources of entropy and generated numbers that are more evenly distributed. Haven't you ever had an itch with wanting to somehow find an answer? Please tell me that you've not gotten to a point where you no longer seek new knowledge randomly.

Comment: haha, you could have just said a no. It's just that some students try to find a shortcut. My bad :)

Comment: If questions of this sort interest you, you might want to take a look at prolog.

Comment: I'm never someone for stating things in very short statements. I usually have the problem of saying too much rather than not enough. And I can imagine that people would try to do something like that on here.

Comment: @Micheal I'll look into it. And this is just one of those random questions that I have about things. It varies from day to day. Some days, I don't even work on my personal projects. A few days back it was about how compilers handle numeric datatypes that are greater than their limit. Which I found out was just "integer overflow" which is done via a modulo. Most of the time I can find it via searching wikipedia/google and also here.

Comment: This question relate to statistics for which many formulas exist for direct probability computation. Your question is laking some information. What is the input data and what output do you want. A well stated question provides half of the answer. Please reformulate your question more precisely.

Comment: I already stated that I wanted it to work for various inputs and various outputs. I wanted it to be a general use formula/algorithm to be applied to everything. Since I don't know what reformatting that You're talking about. I cannot reformat it to include half of the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to worry about the range being from `a` to `b`.  You can just subtract `a*x` from `y` and pretend the range goes from `0` to `b-a`.  (Because each item contributes at least `a` to the sum...  So you can subtract off that `a` once for each of your `x` items.)

Second, note that what you are really trying to do is *count* the number of ways of achieving a particular sum.  The probability is just that count divided by a simple exponential `(b-a+1)^x`.

This problem was covered by "Ask Dr. Math" around a decade ago:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180209013831/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52207.html)

His formulation is assuming dice numbered from 1 to X, so to use his answer, you probably want to shift your range by `a-1` (rather than `a`) to convert it into that form.

His derivation uses generating functions which I feel deserve a little explanation.  The idea is to define a polynomial `f(z)` such that the *coefficient* on `z^n` is the number of ways of rolling `n`.  For a single 6-sided die, for example, this is the generating function:

```
z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5 + z^6
```

...because there is one way of rolling each number from 1 to 6, and zero ways of rolling anything else.

Now, if you have two generating functions `g(z)` and `h(z)` for two sets of dice, it turns out the generating function for the union of those sets is just the product of `g` and `h`. (Stare at the "multiply two polynomials" operation for a while to convince yourself this is true.) For example, for two dice, we can just square the above expression to get:

```
z^2 + 2z^3 + 3z^4 +4z^5 + 5z^6 + 6z^7 + 5z^8 + 4z^9 + 3z^10 + 2z^11 + z^12
```

Notice how we can read the number of combinations directly off of the coefficients:  1 way to get a 2 (`1*z^2`),  6 ways to get a 7 (`6*z^7`), etc.

The cube of the expression would give us the generating function for three dice; the fourth power, four dice; and so on.

The power of this formulation comes when you write the generating functions in closed form, multiply, and then expand them again using the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).  I defer to Dr. Math's explanation for the details.

Comment: I'm glad to know that someone else has already figured this out so long ago. But now I don't know which one would be best to use. If I should use Dr. Math's one which would be doing polynomial to b, and then raising it to the xth value. Or if I should use the other one. Since they seem to solve a similar problem in pretty similar methods. If My understanding of the resulting code is write. I won't guarantee it though, since I'm not some coding wizard.

Comment: This approach makes the assumption that the distribution of each item is independent, isn't it? Seems fair for the dice example, but that wouldn't necessarily be a smart/safe assumption in other areas.

Comment: @Mathias: Yes.  If the probabilities are not independent, the problem becomes much harder to express, never mind solve in closed form.

Comment: I chose this one since it is the approach that I ended up taking with the program that is appended to the end of my first post.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that `f(a, b, n, x)` represents the number of ways you can select n numbers between a and b, which sum up to x.

Then notice that:

```
f(a, b, n, x) = f(0, b-a, n, x-n*a)
```

Indeed, just take one way to achieve the sum of x and from each of the n numbers subtract a, then the total sum will become `x - n*a` and each of them will be between 0 and b-a.

Thus it's enough to write code to find `f(0, m, n, x)`.

Now note that, all the ways to achieve the goal, such that the last number is c is:

```
f(0, m, n-1, x-c)
```

Indeed, we have n-1 numbers left and want the total sum to be x-c.
Then we have a recursive formula:

```
f(0,m,n,x) = f(0,m,n-1,x) + f(0,m,n-1,x-1) + ... + f(0,m,n-1,x-m)
```

where the summands on the right correspond to the last number being equal to 0, 1, ..., m

Now you can implement that using recursion, but this will be too slow.

However, there is a trick called memoized recursion, i.e. you save the result of the function, so that you don't have to compute it again (for the same arguments).

The memoized recursion will have complexity of `O(m * n)`, because that's the number of different input parameters that you need to compute and save.

Once you have computed the count you need to divide by the total number of posiblities, which is (m+1)*n to get the final probability.

Comment: I think I understand what you're talking about here. So the memoization as you called it and wikipedia explained. I store the value in an array of some size for that value. And then from then on I just use that value instead of recalculating it. So for example if I was to store it inside of an array I'll call R it'd be. `R[0]` for the first, `R[1]` for the next and so on. This also seems similar to the Dr. Math one but more programming than math.

Comment: +1 for a pretty answer.  Three comments:  (1) This "memoization" technique is also known as _dynamic programming_.  (2) This algorithm adds m numbers together to compute each element of a m-by-n table, which is `O(n*m^2)` additions, not `O(m*n)`.  (3) I think you meant `(m+1)^n`, not `(m+1)*n`, when you divide to get the probability.

Answer (score 0):

To get all possibilities, you could make a map of values:

```
for (i=a to b) {
 for (j=a to b) {
  map.put(i+j, 1+map.get(i+j))
 }
}
```

For a more efficient way to count sums, you could use the pattern
6 7's, 5 6's, 4 5's, 3 4's, 2 3's, 1 two.

The pattern holds for n x n grid, there will be n (n+1)'s, with one less possibility for a sum 1 greater or less.

This will count the possibilities, for example, Count(6, 1/2/3/4/5/6) will give possibilities for sums of dice.

```
import math
def Count(poss,sumto):
  return poss - math.fabs(sumto-(poss+1));
```

Edit: In C this would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>;

int count(int poss, int sumto)
{
  return poss - abs(sumto-(poss+1));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("With two dice,\n");
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<= 13; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ways to sum to %d\n",count(6,i),i);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

gives:

```
With two dice,
0 ways to sum to 1
1 ways to sum to 2
2 ways to sum to 3
3 ways to sum to 4
4 ways to sum to 5
5 ways to sum to 6
6 ways to sum to 7
5 ways to sum to 8
4 ways to sum to 9
3 ways to sum to 10
2 ways to sum to 11
1 ways to sum to 12
0 ways to sum to 13
```

Comment: This answer is in python. At first I wasn't sure if you were trying to do it in pseudo code, or python since both are almost identical to me in the most basic form. Thanks to you adding the "import math" to it, I now know that it is python and as such is not that useful to me(at least). My understanding of python goes as far as looking at the code and being able to understand how some of the functions work. I know the syntax and I can probably write a bit of it, but it's no where near my favorite nor most well known language.

Answer (score 0):

Number theory, statistics and combinatorics lead you to believe that to arrive at a numerical value for the probability of an event -- well you have to know 2 things:

- the number of possible outcomes
- within the set of total outcomes how many equal the outcome 'y' whose probability value you seek.

In pseudocode:

```
numPossibleOutcomes = calcNumOutcomes(x, a, b);
numSpecificOutcomes = calcSpecificOutcome(y);
probabilityOfOutcome = numSpecificOutcomes / numPossibleOutcomes;
```

Then just code up the 2 functions above which should be easy.

Comment: Please format your answers; walls of text are hard to read. :)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was going to end up doing anyway. Since it still requires me to calculate every single possibility. So I'd have to loop through them all anyway. I was looking for a faster method of this.